# War not Working on External Tomcat after Spring boot upgrade to 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I have my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Also added:

```xml
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Added contextpath in application.properties :

```
server.servlet.context-path=/admin
```

The name of war is also admin.war

I have also extended SpringBootServletInitializer in the main class.

I upgraded the project from Spring Boot version 1.5.9 to 2.6.6.
When the 1.5.9 version was used the war was deployed successfully in external Tomcat. Now it shows as *No mapping found for context Path with version upgrade*. I am using tomcat version 9.0.64 with spring 2.6.6

Comment: Please learn [ask] before posting questions

Answer (score 0):

Try using in properties:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```